# Accelerate Excel VSTO startup time of a Document Customization that uses WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vsto

I have a somewhat complex Excel 2010 Document customization.

This customization also includes WPF user controls inside Custom Task Pane and some popup controls.

The problem is that my customization is taking about 15 seconds to start.

Are there good techniques to optimize this startup time?

My initialization code seems like this:

```
// Create a WPF app inside VSTO to configure resource dictionaries and display language
_wpfApp = new System.Windows.Application();


// Load the resource dictionary
var resources = System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(
    new Uri("ModernCashFlow.WpfControls;component/Resources/CustomResources.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                as System.Windows.ResourceDictionary;

// Merge it on application level
_wpfApp.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);

    // Set WPF's app language to system default - useful for number/date formatting - the default is en-US.
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
                                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try loading your application in a background thread? The advantage is that it will preload the assemblies in memory so that startup time can be reduced. WPF apps are very slow to startup. I would profile timings for each line above until you pinpoint your slowest point.

Comment: @SliverNinja In fact, it did the trick. My startup time reduced greatly. It's about 7 seconds first time after reboot and 3 to 4 secs on warm startups. Thanks!